# Force my python URL request past redirection

Tags: python, redirect, web-scraping, python-requests

The URL I am trying to webscrape from is an actual URL:

https://www.lineups.com/nfl/player-stats/ezekiel-elliott

However if I try to request this site I am (301) redirected. How can I force get to this URL?

I have already tried turning: allow_redirects = False

```
url = "https://www.lineups.com/nfl/player-stats/Matt-Ryan"

r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)

print(r.status_code, r.headers['Location'])  # 301 /nfl/player-stats
print(r.url)  # https://www.lineups.com/nfl/player-stats/Matt-Ryan


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

## Moved Permanently. Redirecting to /nfl/player-stats

Comment: If you want to allow redirects you would set `allow_redirects=True`

Answer (score 0):

On using Session with User-Agent, I am getting 200 response and proper content. The below code works.

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

session.headers.update({'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"})

resp = session.get("https://www.lineups.com/nfl/player-stats/ezekiel-elliott")

print(resp.status_code)

print(resp.text)
```